ASP.NET MVC ListBox with MultiSelect
In ASP.NET MVC, I'm trying to have listbox with checkbox option to each item selection.
I have tried in below method. but the checkbox not appearing beside to each item. thanks in advance.
View
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.btId, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.flg, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })

Model
public void LoadMultiTypeDropdown(int? Id)
{
    List<SelectListItem> TypeSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    var TypeList = _context.Note.Where(a => a.btID == Id);

    TypeSelectList.Add(new NoteCollectionEvntLabAnalysesRequests
    {
        Text = "--Select--",
        Value = ""
    });

    foreach (var item in TypeList)
    {
        TypeSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.Notes,
            Value = item.ID.ToString()
        });
    }
    SelectList ft = new SelectList(TypeSelectList, "Value", "Text");
    ViewData["flg"] = ft;
    
}


